# Has anyone else noticed the spelling error in the "source-criticsm" tag?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

Who can fix it? It says "source-criticsm" but should say "source-criticism"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can fix it :)

Well spotted!